# How can I make this shape in html5 and css3?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How can I make this shape in html5 and css3?

[image]

Comment: What you have there will be two elements. A smaller DIV overlaying a larger DIV or one DIV inside of another DIV. Really depends on the requirements how you'd go about each.

Comment: But I need a text inside the deformated div, any css rule to make this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#big {
        position: relative;
        background: black;
        width: 600px;
        height: 600px;        
    }
    #in {
        position: absolute;
        background: black;
        width: 280px;
        height: 280px;
        bottom:0;
        right: 0;
        border-top: 20px solid white;
    border-left: 20px solid white;
    }
```

```html
<div id="big">
    <div id="in"></div>
</div>
```